# Save as warning for overwriting

Tags: customization

If i save as to a folder where the the file is already in that folder, Blender won't give me a warning, it's just simply overwrite it and it's very dangerous. Is there really no setting to turn this warning on ?

Comment: Have a look in the rendering (output) options. It's the camera icon at right.  Open up the "Output" tab (camera icon) and in there you should see a box called "Overwrite Files".  Also in User preferences under "Files"  at right there are options as to how many copies (versions) it will save,   When it overwrites, it renames the old file to Blend.1, 2, 3 etc.  When you exit, in Blender's "Temporary" folder it places a file there called Quit.Blend,   Blender will also do auto saves every so many minutes.    Hope that helps...

Comment: Blender highlights the file manager name field in red when overwriting